# How to auto delete files from the "dist" folder if you delete prototype from "src"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I'm very new in build systems, that's why sorry for this question.

I have this structure of my boilerplate.

`/src (working folder)
 ___/templates(jade files)
 ___/scss
 ___/scripts
/dist (compiled files)
___/css
___/js
___.html files`

In `templates` folder I have `.jade` files which are compiled to `.html` files. The same thing with `.scss` files. When I create a `.jade` file - that automatically compiled to `.html` and moved to `dist` folder. 
I want to when I delete or rename a file in `src` folder - it automatically happened in a `dist` folder. Here is my `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var csso = require('gulp-csso');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var jade = require('gulp-jade');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

//sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/scss/**/*.scss')
.pipe(plumber())
.pipe(sass())
.pipe(autoprefixer({
  browsers: ['last 5 versions'],
  cascade: false
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
.pipe(rename({
  suffix: '.min'
}))
.pipe(autoprefixer({
  browsers: ['last 5 versions'],
  cascade: false
}))
.pipe(csso())
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
.pipe(browserSync.reload({
  stream: true
}));
});

//browserSync
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
       baseDir: 'dist'
    },
  });
});

//jade
gulp.task('jade', function() {
 return gulp.src('src/templates/**/!(_)*.jade')
.pipe(plumber())
.pipe(jade({
  pretty: true
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
.pipe(browserSync.reload({
  stream: true
}));
});

//scripts
gulp.task('uglify', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/scripts/**/*.js')
.pipe(plumber())
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
.pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
.pipe(uglify({
  mangle: false
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
.pipe(browserSync.reload({
  stream: true
}));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass', 'jade', 'uglify'], function() {
  gulp.watch('src/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('src/templates/**/*.jade', ['jade']);
  gulp.watch('src/scripts/**/*.js', ['uglify']);
});
```

I tried to add this

```
var delDest;
gulp.task('del', function(cb) {
    return del(delDest, cb);
});
```

and in each task function give `delDest` its src eg

```
gulp.task('jade', function() {
    delDest = 'dist/*.html';
```

and in .watch function add

```
gulp.watch('src/templates/**/*.jade', ['del', 'jade']);
```

but it's don't work.
Please. help me to do that. And of course I will be very grateful if you prompt what to change/add/do better in my gulpfile:)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The watcher returned by gulp.watch has the ability to bind events specifically when an add/update/delete happens and execute your custom code. The same has been demonstrated [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/handling-the-delete-event-on-watch.md).

Below is a sample code I am using in my project where I delete .js and .d.ts files from a dev-build folder, when I delete the ts file from the scripts folder.

```
|-dev-build
| |-scripts
|-src
| |-scripts
```

I have a simple folder structure as above and once the ts file is deleted from the src/scripts folder, the files are deleted from the dev-build/scripts folder.

```
gulp.task('deleteWatch', function(){
    var watcher = gulp.watch('./src/scripts/**/*.ts',['compilescripts']);

    watcher.on('change', function(event){
        if (event.type === 'deleted'){
            console.log(event.path + " is deleted. Deleting corresponding .js and .d.ts files from dev-build\\scripts");
            var fileNameBase = path.basename(event.path, '.ts');
            del(['./dev-build/scripts/'+fileNameBase+'.*'])
            .then(function(paths){
                console.log("deleted files: " + paths.join('\n'));
                });
        }
    })
})
```

The npm packages I am using are del and path. You would need to customize the path resolution to fit your project structure. But that is the approach to delete your dist files when a file is deleted from src.